# Unable to select filegroups in a Back Up Database Task of a Maintance Plan

Tags: ssms, database-backups, maintenance-plan, filegroup

I'm trying to automate a nightly database backup with a selected filegroup in SQL Server Management Studio using a Maintenance Plan and SQL Server Agent.

When setting up the task I'm not able to select the radio button 'Files and filegroups'. As soon as I click it, the whole task window disappears.

[Task window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGvFI.png)

When I look at the properties of the task, there is a property 'FileGroupsFiles', but any input like 'PRIMARY' doesn't seems to have effect.

[Task Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwSrB.png)

I think it's a bug, but is there a workaround to manually select the preferred filegroup or a fix?